# Datetime greater than 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, yii

I have column datetime in mysql table.
Default value for this column is '`0000-00-00 00:00:00`'.

Question: what is best way for check value greater than zero?

1. `if (strtotime($datetime)>0)`
2. `if ($datetime=="0000-00-00 00:00:00")`
3. Another way?

P.S: I use Yii framework

Comment: second way , it doesnt require the addition functions to check date

Comment: in the first place, why are you allowing  such value? why not make the column as nullable? and it is easy to filter though. `WHERE columnName IS NULL`

Comment: "make the column as nullable" - is best way, I forgot about it, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's almost always a good idea to compare dates with dates, in which case this would be a good candidate:

```
if (str_to_date($datetime)> str_to_date('0000-00-00 00:00:00'))
```